# How to upload AVAudioRecorder files to Firebase Storage with Swift 5 /SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, avaudiorecorder, avkit

Hi I know this have been asked a few times but I am needing help with uploading user voice recordings to Firebase. When the user records their audio in the app and press the stop button I want the recording to be uploaded and stored in Firebase instead of the user's phone.

Heres the function for recording

```
func startRecording() {
    
    let recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    
    do {
        try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
        try recordingSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to set up recording session")
    }
    let documentPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let audioFilename = documentPath.appendingPathComponent("\(Date().toString(dateFormat: "dd-MM-YY_'at'_HH:mm:ss")).m4a")
    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ]
    
    do {
        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.record()
        
        recording = true
    } catch {
        print("Could not start recording")
    }
}
```

Here is the function when the user stops recording

```
func saveRecording() {
    
    let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
       let directoryContents = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: path, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

       for i in directoryContents {
        user.answersSent.append(CardModel(fullname: question.fullname, username: question.username, imageURL: question.imageURL, question: question.question, fileURL: i, createdAt: getCreationDate(for: i), colorChoice: question.colorChoice))
       }
   
      
            
            user.answersSent.sort(by: { $0.createdAt?.compare($1.createdAt!) == .orderedDescending})
           
            
        
        }
    }
```

Thank you so much for taking the time to read. I spent almost two days trying to figure it out.

Comment: You're asking how to upload a file to Firebase Storage but not included any Firebase code. Big picture is that as you're recording, the 'file' is either being written to memory or disk. When the user clicks stop, you then want to upload that file from memory or disk to Storage. That's pretty well covered in the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Uploading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files). So beyond that, what is the question? Do you have some Firebase code your having difficulty with?

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of letting your URL go out of scope immediately, store it in a property on whatever class is running this functions (if you're doing this in a `View`, move all of the recording logic to an `ObservableObject`).
2. At the end of the recording, now that you have the URL, you won't have to do the `createdAt` sorting, which I assume maybe you're doing to get the most recent file (it's a little unclear to me at this point).
3. Upload the local file using the method described in the Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file):

```
// File located on disk
// Create a reference to the file you want to upload
let audioFileRef = storageRef.child("audioFiles/audioFile.m4a") //adjust this to have a unique name

let uploadTask = audioFileRef.putFile(from: localAudioURL, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
  guard let metadata = metadata else {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    return
  }
  //optionally, delete original local file here
}
```

4. Optionally, delete your local file upon completion of the upload. Also, you could choose to use the temporary directory rather than the documents directory to store the initial recording in the first place.